# Cumulative sum of a georeferenced variable in R

Tags: r, datagrid, sum, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have a number of fishing boat tracks, and I'm trying to detect a certain pattern in their movement using R. In doing so I have reached a point where I have discarded all points of the track where the desired pattern is not occurring within a given time window, and I'm left with the remaining georeferenced points. These points have a score value associated, which measures the 'intensity' of the desired pattern.

track_1[1:10,]:

```
        LAT       LON  SCORE
1  32.34855 -35.49264  80.67
2  31.54764 -35.58691  18.14
3  31.38293 -35.25243  46.70
4  31.21447 -35.25830  22.65
5  30.76365 -35.38881  11.93
6  30.75872 -35.54733  22.97
7  30.60261 -35.95472  35.98
8  30.62818 -36.27024  31.09
9  31.35912 -35.73573  14.97
10 31.15218 -36.38027  37.60
```

The code bellow provides the same data

```
data.frame(cbind(
    LAT=c(32.34855,31.54764,31.38293,31.21447,30.76365,30.75872,30.60261,30.62818,31.35912,31.15218),
    LON=c(-35.49264,-35.58691,-35.25243,-35.25830,-35.38881,-35.54733,-35.95472,-36.27024,-35.73573,-36.38027),
    SCORE=c(80.67,18.14,46.70,22.65,11.93,22.97,35.98,31.09,14.97,37.60)))
```

Because some of these points occur geographically close to each other I need to 'pool' their scores together. Hence, I now need a way to throw this data into some kind of a spatial grid and cumulatively sum the scores of all points that fall in the same cell of the grid. This would allow me to find in what areas a given fishing boat exhibits the pattern I'm after the most (and this is not just about time spent in one place). Ultimately, the preferred output would contain lat and lon for every grid cell (center), and the sum of all scores on each cell. In addition, I would also like to be able to adjust the sizing of the grid cells.

I've looked around and all I can find either does not preserve the georeferenced information, is very inefficient, or performs binning of data. There may already be some answers out there, but it might be the case that I'm not able to recognize them since I'm a bit out of my league on this stuff. Can someone please point me to some direction (package, function, etc.)? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, so I'll vaguely point you in the direction of the raster package, and the overlay functions contained therein...

Comment: How does throwing data into a grid, summing points in the same cell, differ from the binning you describe as undesirable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your lat/lon coordinates, and multiply them by the inverse of your desired grid cell edge lengths, measured in degrees. The result will be a pair of floating point numbers whose integer part identifies the grid cell in question. Take the `floor` of these and you have two numbers describing the cell, which you could `paste` to form a single string. You may add that as a new factor column of your data frame. Then you can perform operations based on that factor, like summarizing values.

Example:

```
latScale <- 2 # one cell for every 0.5 degrees
lonScale <- 2 # likewise
track_1$cell <- factor(with(track_1,
    paste(floor(LAT*latScale), floor(LON*lonScale), sep='.')))
library(plyr)
ddply(track_1, .(cell), summarize,
      LAT=mean(LAT), LON=mean(LON), SCORE=sum(SCORE))
```

If you want to, you can use `weighted.mean` instead of mean. If you don't like these factors, you can put more effort in making them nice (e.g. by using compass directions instead of signs), or drop them altogether and use a pair of integer columns instead.

Comment: **THANK YOU!** It worked like a charm. I can hardly believe these few lines of code solved my problem. In the end I just had to apply a correction to the scores to account for the fact that the area of each cell is different depending on latitude. Other than that I used it as is. What a great outcome to my 1st question on SO! It's a shame I can't up vote it...